# k-critical graph inequality- edges and vertices

Tags: graph-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [critical graph inequality- proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167345/critical-graph-inequality-proof)

I am curious to see a rigorous proof of the following:If $G$ is a $k$-critical graph, then $k(|V(G)|-1)\le2|E(G)|$. Does anyone know if it is a well known inequality and if so where I can find it?